# How should I mount my wall cabinet by this pipe

Tags: drywall, ceiling, pipe

My kitchen has a sewage pipe that runs along the wall near the end of the cabinet run, it is a gallery type kitchen.  The original cabinets were in before the owners decided to add a layer of drywalll to the ceiling.  After removing the cabinets I realized there is a gap of about 1/2 inch because of the new ceiling that was added after the cabinets.  I started to add drywall to complete the ceiling for the new cabinets but am stuck st this random pipe end from the ceiling.

Prior cabinet had the pipe end sticking through the inside of the cabinet.  I might have to do the same but looking for some suggestions on what my options are.  See pics,  the purple drywall is new I ended up cutting it last minute because even after cutting s hole for the pipe I realized the ceiling was very uneven and almost nothing to attach the drywall to.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way it was, with it sticking through the inside of the cabinet, because it's a clean-out. If it's to a drum trap, you *will* need access to it in the future.